# assert react component child(ren) existence/absence using jestjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-boilerplate

I have a component that depending on the props passed to it, renders different child components.

I am using jestjs for testing, and I want to assert that that the "parent" component renders the appropriate children/child based on the props passed in the parent component.

a simplified snippet :

**the parent component**

```
import ComponentA from './componentA'
import ComponentB from './componentB'

function ParentComponent(props) {
  const { step } = props
  switch(step) {
    case 'A':
      return (<ComponentA />)
    case 'B':
      return (<ComponentB />)
  }
}
```

**the test**

```
import ParentComponent from './ParentComponent'
import ComponentA from './ComponentA'
import ComponentB from './ComponentB'

const renderCompo = (props = {}) => mount(
  <ParentComponent step={'A'} {...props} />
)

describe('ParentComponent', () => {

  it('should render the <ComponentA /> as its child when passed `A` as the value of step props', () => {
    const renderedComponent = renderCompo()
    // I know this is not correct use of find but this serve as illustration of what I'm trying to assert
    expected(renderedComponent.find(<ComponentA />).length).toEqual(1)
  })
  it('should NOT render the <ComponentB /> as its child when passed `A` as the value of step props', () => {
    const renderedComponent = renderCompo()
    // I know this is not correct use of find but this serve as illustration of what I'm trying to assert
    expected(renderedComponent.find(<ComponentA />).length).toEqual(0)
  })

  it('should render the <ComponentB /> as its child when passed `B` as the value of step props', () => {
    const renderedComponent = renderCompo({ step: 'B' })
    expected(renderedComponent.find(<ComponentB />).length).toEqual(1)
  })
  it('should render the <ComponentA /> as its child when passed `B` as the value of step props', () => {
    const renderedComponent = renderCompo({ step: 'B' })
    expected(renderedComponent.find(<ComponentB />).length).toEqual(0)
  })
})
```

I tried various way to assert this but with no luck.

I know how to use the find method to - for instance - search a `div` or a `h3`, but I would like to test the children against a react component and not the root DOM node the child renders as it might be the same DOM node in different components.

–––––––––––––––––––
EDIT :
–––––––––––––––––––

Using

```
expect(renderedComponent.find(ComponentA).length).toEqual(1)
```

actually work perfectly

My component was not up to spec.

Answer (score 1):

Try explicitly mounting the component with the props you want in each `it`. Then as you are using Jest you can use the `.toMatchSnapshot()` method. You can then open the snapshot files that are generated to make sure everything is rendering as you would expect.

Note you will need [enzyme-to-json](https://github.com/adriantoine/enzyme-to-json) for the below example to work

```
it('should render the <ComponentA /> as its child when passed `A` as the value of step props', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<ParentComponent step={'A'} />)
    expected(toJson(wrapper)).toMatchSnapshot()
  });
it('should render the <ComponentB /> as its child when passed `B` as the value of step props', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<ParentComponent step={'B'} />)
    expected(toJson(wrapper)).toMatchSnapshot()
  })
```

Comment: Thanks For the response, trying to avoid the extra dependency – if un understand correctly, I need at least react-test-renderer – I went back into doing again what I already tried.
That's when I found out that my test were working using : 
`expect(renderedComponent.find(ComponentA).length).toEqual(1)`
The problem was my code wasn't up to spec (or the idea I had of it writing the test).

Comment: Whats the reason for not wanting extra dependencies? This would only require extra dev dependencies so wouldn't bloat your app. Glad you got it working but I would highly recommend looking into spanshot testing. It will save you a lot of time and headaches in the future.

Comment: I agree I think there is good thing to it, to ease creating/editing tests, I intend to check snapshot out. The thing is... the dead-line on this project,